# Big JSON Strings in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I get Big **JSON** Objects (about 1.5 MB) in the `Controller` **C1**. I stringify it and then keep them in a hidden label in the `View` **V1**.

I use the **JSON** in **V1** by parsing it in the `JavaScript` **J1**.

I recently saw a

> Out of Memory Exception

in the **ASP.NET MVC** page once in a while.

I am not sure if the big **JSON** strings in `View` **V1** are causing the issue.

1. Could the big **JSON** strings be the issue for the OOM Exception?
2. Is there a better way to use the big **JSON** strings in **JavaScript** J1?

Answer (score 0):

First some questions:

- When you have this exception?
- When you render your `View`?
- When `js` try to deal with your big object in browser?
- Or maby in `Controller` when you try to get this object?

Anyway if you have this error on **Server side**: your string object is larger than *85000 bytes* so your object goes to [LOH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx). That means that your object will be stored in memory for competitive long time until GC at last free memory. And if you use your controller method frequent you definatly can face OOM problem. Try to profile your application under production pressure and take a look at your memory.

Comment: I see when rendering the view which uses the big json strings.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you're doing on your `View` and inside `Controller`?